# How to change the color of a select arrow in React Native using NativeBase?

Tags: react-native, user-experience, native-base

I'm trying to change the arrow color, but I don't have any idea how to change it to white, for example.
[select imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNaOu.png)

Anyone know how to change the arrow color?

my select code:

```
      <Box maxW="300" alignSelf="flex-start">
        <Select
          color={isDarkTheme ? "white" : "white"}
          minWidth="180"
          selectedValue={measure}
          accessibilityLabel="Testss"
          placeholder={"Test"}
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          borderColor={isDarkTheme ? "#22202E" : "#E7E9F6"}
          fontWeight= 'bold'
          bg={isDarkTheme ? "#7860F5" : "#905CEC"}
          variant= 'rounded'
          _selectedItem={{
            bg: isDarkTheme ? "#404040" : "#EAEAEA",
            placeholder: isDarkTheme ? "#404040" : "#EAEAEA",
            endIcon: <CheckIcon size="5" />,
          }}
          _item={{
            bg: isDarkTheme ? "#333333": "white",
            _text: {
              color: isDarkTheme ? "white": "black", // Definindo a cor do texto como branco
            },
          }}
          _actionSheetContent={{
            bg: isDarkTheme ? "#333333": "white",
          }}
          mt={1}
          onValueChange={handleValueChange}
        >
          <Select.Item label="Test1" value="teste1" />
          <Select.Item label="Test2" value="teste2" />  
        </Select>
      </Box>
```